Syntax error when Printing tuple - Invalid non-printable character
Invalid non-printable character U+200B. Python 3.12.3
days = ('пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс')
steps = [5252, 785875, 7858, 787, 8755, 877, 597]

rar = []​
for i in range(len(days)):
    typle = days[i], steps[i]
    rar.append(typle)

print(rar)

doesn't even print the first element days
print(days[0])


UPD: Found a solution - remove empty lines and rar declaration

If I see correctly, you have zero-width-space (0x200b) after rar = [] -> remove this line and type it again.

Are you using a plain text editor?

@Chris I use the standard python editor (Python IDLE)

There's literally an extra character at the end of rar!
>>> """rar = []​
... """
'rar = []\u200b\n'

Otherwise this works fine for me, though I'd improve it with zip()
days  = ('пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс')
steps = [5252, 785875, 7858, 787, 8755, 877, 597]

rar = []
for day, step in zip(days, steps):
    rar.append((day, step))

print(rar)


Even simpler: rar = list(zip(days, steps))

Thank you. your zip method works, but I'm learning Python and an assignment requires me to do this. I'm not familiar with the zip method and it won't be accepted

anytime - it might still be worth a commit about zip() in your response to the assignment .. a better text editor such as emacs, vim, or Notepad++ can show or alert you to non-printing characters like this!

@AngryFox oh, if you'd meant this solution won't work, your solution is fine, just remove the non-printing character at the end of rar = []​ 

@ti7 yes, I found the hidden symbol using Notepad++: View->Show Symbol->Show all characters. Thanks
